# Parse date from Apple receipt validation server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a datetime from Apple's receipt validation server. I need to compare it to today's date. I'm trying to use moment.js but I am fine with native `Date` as well.

The date is formatted like this, in what [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) claim, [incorrectly](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70335), is RFC 3339 format:

```
2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/GMT
```

Since this isn't a valid RFC 3339 or ISO 8601 datetime, it is failing to parse using moment.js or `Date.parse()`. How can I parse it?

Note that I don't want to simply strip the `Etc/` out because its important for determining the correct timezone according to  https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-230/zic.tproj/datfiles/etcetera:

> We use POSIX-style signs in the Zone names and the output abbreviations, even though this is the opposite of what many people expect. POSIX has positive signs west of Greenwich, but many people expect positive signs east of Greenwich.  For example, TZ='Etc/GMT+4' uses the abbreviation "GMT+4" and corresponds to 4 hours behind UTC (i.e. west of Greenwich) even though many people would expect it to mean 4 hours ahead of UTC (i.e. east of Greenwich).

Answer (score 1):

You can adopt one of two strategies:

1. Manually parse the string and use the parts for the Date constructor, then adjust for the timezone.
2. Transform the timestamp into a string that should be supported by most browsers in use (i.e. ISO 8601 extended format per ECMA-262).

The first way is more robust.

The reference doesn't say how timezones like +0530 are represented in the Etc/ format, so the following doesn't deal with them:

- 'Etc/GMT' becomes '+00:00'
- 'Etc/GMT+4' becomes '-04:00'
- 'Etc/GMT-10' becomes '+10:00'

Also, the following functions don't validate the format, they assume the supplied string is suitable.

```js
// Parse strings in format 2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/GMT
function parsePOZIX(s) {
  var b = s.split(' ');
  // These are the date and time parts
  var c = b[0].split(/\D/).concat(b[1].split(/\D/));
  // Create a new Date using UTC
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(c[0],c[1]-1,c[2],c[3],c[4],c[5]));
  
  // Now adjust for the timezone
  var tz = b[2].split('/')[1];
  var sign = /^\+/.test(tz) ? 1 : -1;
  var hr = tz.replace(/\D/g, '') || '0';
  d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() + sign*hr);
  return d;
}

['2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/GMT',
'2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/+8',
'2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/-10'].forEach(function(s){
  console.log(s + '\n' + parsePOZIX(s).toISOString());
});
```

And the second (less reliable way) which parses and reformats the string, then uses the built-in parser:

```js
// Reformat strings like 2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/GMT 
// to ISO 8601 compliance, then use built-in parser
function parsePOSIX2(s) {
  var b = s.split(' ');
  var tz = b[2].split('/')[1];
  var sign = /^\+/.test(tz)? '-' : '+';
  var hr = tz.replace(/\D/g,'') || '0';
  hr = ('0' + hr).slice(-2) + ':00'; // Must include colon for Safari
  return new Date(b[0] + 'T' + b[1] + sign + hr);
}

['2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/GMT',
 '2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/-4'].forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s + '\n' + parsePOSIX2(s).toISOString());
});
```

Note that Safari will not parse a timezone like "+0000" (resulting in an invalid date), it must include a colon: "+00:00".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to parse an an arbitrary format is to use some regex to split it to pieces, then arrange it in a format you can use.

```js
const date = '2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/GMT';

const [,year,month,day,hour,minute,second,timezone] = date.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\sEtc\/([A-Z]{3})/);

console.log(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timezone);

const parsedDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day} ${hour}:${minute}:${second} ${timezone}`);
console.log(parsedDate);
```

The nice thing about this approach is it works for any random format you may come across (you just need a different regex). With ES6 destructing, it can be quite compact.

Note: I'm not sure if that `Etc` bit is constant or has special meaning, so you should check out the spec and make sure you don't need to do anything with it.

Comment: Looks like your regex is just removing the `Etc` bit. But I need this timezone to match perfectly. The date is the RFC 3339 standard, if I remove pieces I'll likely have timezone bugs. Is there no way to do this is a more standard way?

Comment: This results in a non–standard timestamp, so parsing falls back to implementation specific heuristics. So the result is unreliable: it returns *null* in Safari since a timezone of "GMT" is invalid. Also, I don't see how it deals with timezones like "Etc/+8".

Answer (score 0):

The format Apple is returning consists of an ISO 8601 datetime followed by an IANA timezone. That's an eccentric format I've never seen elsewhere, and it seems to be a mistake on Apple's part given that their docs claim it's meant to be an RFC 3339 datetime string.

JavaScript has no built-in support for working with IANA timezones. For that matter, nor does the core Moment.js library. However, [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) does. If you include both the moment and moment-timezone libraries, then you can parse your date like this:

```
/**
 * Parse a datetime string returned from the Apple Receipt Validation Server, in
 * a format like:
 *     2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/GMT
 * and return its value as a Moment datetime object.
 */
function parseAppleDatetime(appleDatetimeStr) {
    const [dateStr, timeStr, timezoneStr] = appleDatetimeStr.split(' '),
          datetimeStr = dateStr + ' ' + timeStr;
    return moment.tz(datetimeStr, timezoneStr);
}
```

Now if you do, for instance:

```
parseAppleDatetime('2017-11-28 23:37:52 Etc/GMT').format()
```

... you'll get:

```
"2017-11-28T23:37:52Z"
```